# R hangs when fitting logistic regression model with offset using glmnet

Tags: r, glmnet

I'm trying to fit a regularized logistic regression model with an offset using `glmnet`. However, I have found that R becomes unresponsive if any of the offset values are less than about -2 or greater than about +2. For example:

```
library(glmnet)
data(BinomialExample)

# This is fine
glmnet(x, y, family="binomial", offset = rep(-1.9, 100))

# This causes R to become unresponsive
glmnet(x, y, family="binomial", offset = rep(-2.1, 100))
```

Any ideas about what might be happening? As far I can tell this only affects binomial models.

Comment: Most likely because your offset doesn't make sense for the data.